# Can i use ObjectContext without use of EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectcontext

I use ObjectContext using system.data.entity namespace,
what is difference between Entity Framework and this namespace,
is it implementation and this is interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Entity Framework 6, this library was part of .NET releases, thus, mostly pre-6th version classes, enumerations, interfaces or whatever are still there ([see this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/entity-framework-and-open-source))

Now Entity Framework is distributed as NuGet package and this and other objects are in other namespaces. For example, [see where's the Entity Framework 6's `ObjectContext` class (follow the link):](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

> Namespace:  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects
>
> Assembly:  EntityFramework (in EntityFramework.dll)